# ¿Qué significa "ha leído cuanto caso policial y manual de medicina forense existe"?

Tags: traducción

> Está muy bien preparada, ha leído **cuanto caso policial** y manual de
>   medicina forense **existe**, y dice que Mike O'ʹKelly y ella podrían
>   realizar una autopsia sobre la mesa de la cocina con la mayor
>   facilidad.

La palabra "existe" parece fuera de lugar y el número singular de *cuanto caso* también me lanza para un lazo.

Comment: Curiosa expresión la de _me lanza para un lazo_. ¿Qué quiere decir?

Comment: @fedorqui Tratando de decir o encontrar el mismo que "throw me for a loop" en inglés, o me causa problemas.

Comment: These expressions have thrown me for a loop: Estas expresiones me tienen confundido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En este caso la palabra *cuanto* hace referencia a la [segunda acepción del DLE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BSKWl78):

> 2. adj. relat. Ante nombres contables en singular empleados como no contables, denota ponderación o pluralidad.

El ejemplo que pone es el siguiente:

> Compra cuanta silla antigua encuentra.

Que vendría a significar lo mismo que:

> Compra todas las sillas antiguas que encuentra.

Por tanto, la frase que comentas significa que ha leído todos los casos policiales que existen (es decir, aquellos para los cuales existe documentación escrita). Y lo mismo para los manuales forenses, ha leído todos los que ha encontrado (los que existen para ella).

Comment: Otra manera de explicarlo: *ha leído todos los casos policial y manuales de medicina forense que existen.*